# Group-By for every half month date range

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I need help with a query to sum all values by month grouped by period of 15 days.

Trying:

```
SELECT  sum(price) From table WHERE ADD_DATE( date, INTERVAL 15 DAY);
```

expected result:

```
Jan Day 1 - 15 = 5.2
Jan Day 16 - 31 = 80.4

Feb Day 1 - 15 = 50
Feb Day 16 - 28 = 80.2
.....
```

Comment: Is it always explicitly 15 days?  And how long an overall duration do you want... a range, year?  will interval change for different groupings?

Comment: Yeah always 15 days !!! duration  a range year, no change grouping

Comment: You know that January 16-31 is 16 days? And February 16-28 is 13 days?

Answer (score 4):

This basically does the extract broken down from 1-15 and 16-end of the month.
MySQL has a nice simple function "Last_Day()" which returns the last day of a given month

```
select
        CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%b %Y Day ' ),
            case when dayofmonth( `date` ) < 16
                then '01-15'
                else CONCAT( '16-', right( last_day( `date` ), 2)  )
                end ) as CharMonth,
        sum( price ) as TotalPrice
    from 
        invoice
    group by
        CharMonth
    order by
        year( `date` ),
        month( `date` ),
        min( dayofmonth( `date` ))
```

The above would show an example of

```
CharOfMonth         TotalPrice
Dec 2011 Day 01-15  226.98
Dec 2011 Day 16-31  108.12
Jan 2012 Day 01-15  983.08
Jan 2012 Day 16-31  235.02
Feb 2012 Day 01-15  271.29
Feb 2012 Day 16-29  382.91
Mar 2012 Day 01-15  900.28
```

The purpose of the order by in this example that spans a year is to ensure all 2011 before 2012.  Subsequently, I don't want the months in alpha order where "Feb" would appear before "Jan", and even the 01-15 and 16-?? could be swapped order, so I'm explicitly ordering by the year(), month() and MINIMUM day within each group... ie: force data with lowest day within the group... ie: 1-15 vs 16 to whatever...

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the job:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS price_sum, month_half FROM
(
  SELECT price, 
  IF(
    DATEDIFF(`date`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m-01")) > 15,
    CONCAT(
      DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%b %Y Day 16 - "), 
      DATE_FORMAT(
      DATE_SUB(
        DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%Y-%m-01"), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 
      INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%d"
      )
    ),
    DATE_FORMAT(`date`, "%b %Y Day 1 - 15")
    ) AS month_half,
  `date` AS order_date  
  FROM table WHERE 
  `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
) AS t 
GROUP BY month_half ORDER BY order_date
```

What happens here is that i use **DATEDIFF** to find the number of days since the start of the month and thus find in which half of the month the *date* value corresponds to.
Also I used **DATE_SUB** along with **DATE_ADD** to find the last day of the month (for display reasons).

I added the **%Y** format parameter in case this spans for a date range longer than 1 year, in which case you'll have repeated month names.

Hope it helps. Cheers.